# about the indexof(" ")

Tags: java, indexof, spaces

```
String str = "1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th 7th 8th 9th 10th";

        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;

        int temp3 = str.indexOf(" ");
        int i = 0;
        int x = 6;

        while(i < x){
            System.out.println("current start: " + start);
            start = str.indexOf(" ", temp3);

            i++;
            temp3 += str.indexOf(" ");
        }
        end = str.indexOf(" ", start + 1);

        String sample = str.substring(start, end);
        System.out.println("HERE: " + sample);
```

I am writing a program that would allow the user to input a number and print the particular place from the string, for example

```
String str = "1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th 7th 8th 9th 10th";
```

when the user input 0, it prints 1st or when he input 1, it prints 2nd

so the way that I decide how to make it is to find the index of the two spaces which includes the particular string:"`1st" or "2nd" or "3rd".....`, and assign those index into two variables called start and end. And take both as a parameter of the substring to print the particular string

and in the code above, it works until the variable x is 6, here is the output:

```
current start: 0
current start: 3
current start: 7
current start: 11
current start: 15
current start: 15
HERE:  6th
```

it repeats 15 twice and the string shouldn't be 6th, it should be:

0: 1st, 
1: 2nd, 
2: 3rd,
3: 4th,
4: 5th,
5: 6th,
6: 7th
and so on...

and also not only 6, when the varriable x is 10, it also repeat a number 27 twice

I tried to find the problem, but I have no idea

do anyone know what is the problem is? and how to fix it?

thank you

Comment: You should take a look at the [`split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method

Comment: yea, split work perfect in my program, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your solution. The string doesn't end on a space so if you try to find the end at

```
end = str.indexOf(" ", start + 1);
```

for the last element you will get -1.

Also when you're in the loop you want temp3 to point to the next space location but you assign temp as

```
temp3 += str.indexOf(" ");
```

This will always add 3 to temp3, but When the number of elements increases the number of characters isn't always 3, for example "10th" takes 4 characters, so you can't just add on 3 characters to temp3.

I think what you need there is something like

```
temp3 = start+1
```

and you will soon realize you don't need temp3 at all.

A much simpler solution would be to split the string by space and then return the xth element like so.

```
    String str = "1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th 7th 8th 9th 10th";

    int x = 6;

    String[] tokens = str.split(" ");

    System.out.println(tokens[x]);
```

Comment: never know there have split, and yea it works exactly what I want , thank you :)

Comment: no problem, java has a lot of features built in for free !

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that need attention in the code, but mainly, your bug boils down to this line:

```
start = str.indexOf(" ", temp3); // why temp3?
```

...combined with the inexplicable:

```
temp3 += str.indexOf(" "); // no idea what this is trying to do.
```

Instead, just remove the `temp3` variable altogether, and perform the `indexOf` like this:

```
start = str.indexOf(" ", start + 1); // start + 1: look right after the last space that was found.
```